# How to format a string in a TextField without changing it's value with JavaFX

Tags: javafx-8

I am trying to change the value of a `TextField` for display only. Ie - when users attempt to enter phone number, they only enter the digits and when they leave the field, it displays formatted without changing the data in the field.

Let's say I have a `TextField` for a phone number and it should allow digits only, maximum of 10 characters:

2085551212

I can handle that with a `TextFormatter` using a `UnaryOperator`.

```
 UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> filter = new UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change>() {
      @Override
      public TextFormatter.Change apply(TextFormatter.Change change) {
           int maxlength = 14;

           if(change.getControlText().indexOf('(') == -1) {
                maxlength = 10;
           }

           System.out.println(change);

           if (change.getControlText().length() + change.getText().length() >= maxlength) {
                int maxPos = maxlength - change.getControlText().length();
                change.setText(change.getText().substring(0, maxPos));
           }

           String text = change.getText();

           for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
                if (!Character.isDigit(text.charAt(i)))
                     return null;

           return change;
      }
 };
```

However I would like to format the value to be when it's 10 characters long (likely unformatted when != 10):

(208) 555-1212

When I use a `TextFormatter` to format it, it changes the value of the string to (208) 555-1212.  We store only the digits in the database 2085551212.

I attempted this with a `StringConverter`.  But I couldn't make it work.  In the `toString()` method I strip out the formatting, however when I do that my `TextField` doesn't display.

```
 StringConverter<String> formatter = new StringConverter<String>() {
      @Override
      public String fromString(String string) {
           System.out.println("fromString(): before = " + string);

           if (string.length() == 14) {
                System.out.println("fromString(): after = " + string);

                return string;
           } else if (string.length() == 10 && string.indexOf('-') == -1) {
                String result =  String.format("(%s) %s-%s", string.substring(0, 3), string.substring(3, 6),
                    string.substring(6, 10));
                System.out.println("fromString(): after = " + result);

                return result;
           } else {
                return null;
           }
      }

      @Override
      public String toString(String object) {

           System.out.println("toString(): before = " + object);

           if(object == null) {
                return "";
           }

           Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\p{Punct}\\p{Blank}]", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
           Matcher m = p.matcher(object);
           object = m.replaceAll("");

           System.out.println("toString(): after = " + object);

           return object;
      }
 };
```

I bound to a `TextField` like this which I assumed would work:

```
 txtPhone.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>(formatter, null, filter));
 t2.textProperty().bindBidirectional(foo.fooPropertyProperty(), formatter); //I was just testing to see the results in another textfield to see if it would work.
```

So I am at a loss.  I essentially want to allow only digits and then when the user leaves the field present the value in a formatted way - without actually changing the string value that goes to the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing the purpose of `toString()` and `fromString()` methods with each other in your converter. `toString()` converts the value property of your text editor to the displayed text, not the other way around. Try switching the code in these methods and it should work.

The reason why your text field does not display anything after loosing focus is because `fromString()` method is called and returns null (from the `else` clause). This commits `null` to the value property of your editor. The change in value property updates the displayed text (textProperty) by calling `toString(null)` which changes the text property of your editor to an empty string.

**EDIT**

Below is my test code that is a follow-up to the discussion in the comments. I reused a large amount of your original code. I created an FXML JavaFX project and defined `TextField` and `Label` in FXML file. The `TextField` accepts user's input and formats it. The `Label` displays value of the text formatter (only digits) that should go to the database. The value is accessible by calling `formatter.valueProperty().get()`. I hope it helps.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

// label displays phone number containing only digits (for database)
@FXML private Label label;

/* field displays formatted text (XXX)-XXX-XXXX after user types
10 digits and presses Enter or if the field looses focus */
@FXML private TextField field;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> filter = new UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change>() {
        @Override
        public TextFormatter.Change apply(TextFormatter.Change change) {
            if (!change.isContentChange()) {
                /* nothing is added or deleted but change must be returned 
                 * as it contains selection info and caret position
                 */
                return change;
            }

            int maxlength = 14;
            if (change.getControlText().indexOf('(') == -1) {
                maxlength = 10;
            }

            if (change.getControlNewText().length() > maxlength
                    || change.getText().matches("\\D+")) {
                // invalid input. Cancel the change
                return null;
            }
            return change;
        }
    };

    StringConverter<String> converter = new StringConverter<String>() {

        // updates displayed text from commited value
        @Override
        public String toString(String commitedText) {
            if (commitedText == null) {
                // don't change displayed text
                return field.getText();
            }

            if (commitedText.length() == 10 && !commitedText.matches("\\D+")) {
                return String.format("(%s) %s-%s", commitedText.substring(0, 3), commitedText.substring(3, 6),
                                     commitedText.substring(6, 10));
            } else {
                /* Commited text can be either null or 10 digits.
                 * Nothing else is allowed by fromString() method unless changed directly
                 */
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "Unexpected or incomplete phone number value: " + commitedText);
            }
        }

        // commits displayed text to value
        @Override
        public String fromString(String displayedText) {
            // remove formatting characters
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\p{Punct}\\p{Blank}]", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(displayedText);
            displayedText = m.replaceAll("");

            if (displayedText.length() != 10) {
                // user is not done typing the number. Don't commit
                return null;
            }

            return displayedText;
        }
    };
    TextFormatter<String> formatter = new TextFormatter<String>(converter, "1234567890", filter);
    field.setTextFormatter(formatter);
    label.textProperty().bind(formatter.valueProperty());
 }
}
```

Comment: I tried both ways but it still doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: I have just tested it myself and it works. When you submit the value to the database you need to read value property of the formatter. First create a reference to your formatter object before setting it to the `TextField`: `TextFormatter<String> formatter = new TextFormatter<String>(formatter, "1234567890", filter);`. Then your database can read digit-only-text via `formatter.valueProperty().get()`.

Comment: This is still causing issues.  First time it works, second time it shows the formatted value.  I might just abandon using text formatters for this and use other means.  It's too bad that this doesn't work in a simple and easy way.

Comment: My apologies. That’s because my code was missing `object = m.replaceAll("");` which was in your original code. I don’t know how it happened. I think using text formatters is the right way to do it. Let me fix my answer again, the third time. The new edit addresses the problems you discovered and contains other improvements. Note the text is not converted to a non-null value unless it the phone number is complete. This seems right for your task.