# Gluon TextField Input Mask

Tags: gluon

How to put some input mask like '999.999.999-99' on Gluon TextField. I could build a new component inheriting from JavaFX TextField but I'd rather use Gluon TextField because it fits best on mobile.
I tried using StringConverter but it did not work.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use a `TextFormatter` in a JavaFX `TextField`, and with Gluon Mobile it will work fine on mobile. What is your use case?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, about my use case, we are bringing our ERP to mobile, and we have found some issues when trying to work with formatted form fields, we tried using JFoenix (which found some issues) and pure JavaFX TextField, but lacks some resources like floatText, maxLength, etc. here are some app images: https://www.suiteone.com.br/#sobre

Comment: We need formatted fields to use formats like phone numbers, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current Gluon Mobile `TextFiled` control does support floating text, max length count, and other features, but doesn't allow a `TextFormatter` *directly*.

If you have a look with ScenicView, the Gluon control is built upon a JavaFX `TextField` control.

While a text formatter is added to the control, using a `lookup`, you can get access to the  internal JavaFX `TextField` and apply it.

If you are using a `View` created with FXML (Glisten-Afterburner template), that contains a Gluon Mobile `TextField`, you could just get the JavaFX one:

```
@FXML
private TextField gluonTextField;

public void initialize() {
    gluonTextField.setFloatText("Insert phone number");

    primary.setOnShown(e -> {
        javafx.scene.control.TextField javafxTextField = (javafx.scene.control.TextField) primary.lookup(".text-input");
        if (javafxTextField != null) {
            javafxTextField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(...));
        }
    }
}
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751922/how-to-format-a-string-in-a-textfield-without-changing-its-value-with-javafx) for a possible implementation of a `TextFormatter` for phone numbers.